No se por qué la variable "word" es NULL


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letters = ["A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e","F","f","G","g","H","h","I","i","J","j","K","k","L","l","M","m","N","n","O","o","P","p","Q","q","R","r","S","s","T","t","U","u","V","v","W","w","X","x","Y","y","Z","z"];
var special_letters = ["Ñ","ñ","Á","á","Ä","ä","ë","Ë","é","É","Ï","ï","Í","í","ö","Ö","Ó","ó","Ü","ü","ú","Ú"];
var special_2 = [".",",",";",":","/","*","-","+","?","¡","!","¿","#","$","%","&","@","|","°","]","[","´","'","¨","-","_","(",")"];
var numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letC = ["q","j","A","i","R","a","W","T","s","G","t","h","Y","J","S","C","b","u","D","V","H","y","l","I","o","n","f","F","Q","p","N","Z","O","P","x","L","r","z","k","g","U","E","m","d","w","v",,"c","B",,"M","K","X","e"];
var splC = ["É","Á","Ë","ä","ñ","Ü","ö","Ó","Ö","Í","ï","í","Ñ","Ä","ü","á","ú","ë","ó","Ï","Ú","é"];
var spC2 = ["|","-","¨",")","*","&",";","/",":","?","(","_","'","%","+","¿","[","#","°","´",".","¡","]","$",",","@","!","-"];
var numC = ["7","5","6","8","2","0","9","3","4","1"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function Encrip(letters,special_2,special_letters,numbers,numC,spC2,splC,letC) {

    let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips"));
    let Encrips = word.split([""]);
    
    let ReadL = letters;
    let ReadLC = letC;
    let ReadSPL = special_letters;
    let ReadSPLC = splC;
    let ReadSP2 = special_2;
    let ReadSPC2 =  spC2;
    let ReadNum = numbers;
    let ReadNumC = numC;

        let a = 0;
        let b = 0;
        let c = 0
        let d = 0;
    
        for(let i = 0;i > ReadL.length;i++){

            if(Encrips[a]=ReadL[i]){
                Encrips[a] = ReadLC[i];
                a++;
            }else if (i = ReadL.length) {
                i = 0;
                a++;
            }
            if
            (a = Encrips.length) {
                break;
            }
        }    

        for(let j = 0;j < ReadNum.length;j++){

            if(Encrips[b]=ReadNum[j]){
                Encrips[b] = ReadNumC[j];
                b++;
            }else if (j = ReadNum.length) {
                j = 0;
                b++;
            }
            if(b = Encrips.length) {
                b = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(let l = 0;l < ReadSPL.length;l++){

            if(Encrips[c]=ReadSPL[l]){
                Encrips[c] = ReadSPLC[l];
                c++;
            }else if (l = ReadSPL.length) {
                l = 0;
                c++;
            }
            if
            (c = Encrips.length) {
                c = 0;
                break;
            }
        } 
        for(let g = 0;g < ReadSP2.length;g++){

            if(Encrips[d]=ReadSP2[g]){
                Encrips[d] = ReadSPC2[g];
                d++;
            }else if (g = ReadSP2.length) {
                g = 0;
                d++;
            }
            if
            (d = Encrips.length) {
                d = 0;
                break;
            }
                        
        }
        let newUnEn = Encrips.join();
        var changelog = document.getElementsById("NewUn");
        
        return(changelog.appendChild(newUnEn));
}
<form action="#" method="get">

    <span class="mainb">

        <label name="crips">Inserte palabra</label>
        <input type="text" for="crips" id="NewCrips">

        <button type="submit" class="buttons" onclick="Encrip()">Encriptar</button>
        <button type="reset" class="buttons">Reiniciar</button>

        <label for="Uncrips">Desencriptar</label>
        <input type="text" for="Uncrips" id="NewUN">
        <button type="submit" onclick="UnCrip()" class="buttons">Uncrip</button>

    </span>
 </form>




Tu variable Word es null porque en:
let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips"));

Estas seleccionando un tag HTML, es decir esa query busca el siguiente elemento <NewCrips></NewCrips> en el documento, lo cual evidentemente no existe. Para seleccionar un elemento HTML por su id usando querySelector debes usar el prefijo # --> document.querySelector("#NewCrips")
Y tampoco va a resultar, porque estás queriendo convertir un elemento HTML en String, lo que tú quieres es capturar su el valor del input (que ya es string):
let word = document.querySelector("NewCrips").value;

Por otro lado, tienes un sin número de errores en tú código que ya otros compañeros te lo explicaron
Por lo que yo quiero ahondar en tu código. Entiendo que a partir de una series de array (a modo de diccionario) transformas cada carácter en otro carácter.
Hay una forma mucho más simple de hacer lo mismo. Que es unir todos los diccionarios y luego hacer un map()
Luego para desencriptar solo hay que intercambiar de lugares los array:
     Encrips.map(a => arrayC[arrayL.indexOf(a)]).join("");
//se cambian lugares    ↕      ↕
  DesEncrips.map(a => arrayL[arrayC.indexOf(a)]).join("");



const letters = ["A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e","F","f","G","g","H","h","I","i","J","j","K","k","L","l","M","m","N","n","O","o","P","p","Q","q","R","r","S","s","T","t","U","u","V","v","W","w","X","x","Y","y","Z","z"];

const special_letters = ["Ñ", "ñ", "Á", "á", "Ä", "ä", "ë", "Ë", "é", "É", "Ï", "ï", "Í", "í", "ö", "Ö", "Ó", "ó", "Ü", "ü", "ú", "Ú"];
const special_2 = [".",",",";",":","/","*","-","+","?","¡","!","¿","#","$","%","&","@","|","°","]","[","´","'","¨","-","_","(",")"];
const numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const letC =    ["q","j","A","i","R","a","W","T","s","G","t","h","Y","J","S","C","b","u","D","V","H","y","l","I","o","n","f","F","Q","p","N","Z","O","P","x","L","r","z","k","g","U","E","m","d","w","v","c","B","M","K","X","e"];
const splC = ["É","Á","Ë","ä","ñ","Ü","ö","Ó","Ö","Í","ï","í","Ñ","Ä","ü","á","ú","ë","ó","Ï","Ú","é"];
const spC2 = ["|","-","¨",")","*","&",";","/",":","?","(","_","'","%","+","¿","[","#","°","´",".","¡","]","$",",","@","!","-"];
const numC = ["7","5","6","8","2","0","9","3","4","1"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//unimos los array
const arrayL = letters.concat(special_letters).concat(special_2).concat(numbers);
const arrayC = letC.concat(splC).concat(spC2).concat(numC);

function Encrip(word) {
    let Encrips = word.split("");
    return Encrips.map(a => arrayC[arrayL.indexOf(a)]).join("");    
}

function DesEncrip(word) {
    let DesEncrips = word.split("");
    return DesEncrips.map(a => arrayL[arrayC.indexOf(a)]).join("");    
}

console.log(Encrip("Wolvering"));
console.log(Encrip("Deadpool"));

console.log(DesEncrip("wpIdGLuFJ"));
console.log(DesEncrip("WGjTZppI"));




Independientemente de que esto sirva para encriptar / desencriptar realmente, lo cual es otro asunto1, hay varios problemas en tu código, a saber:

Considera agregar event.preventDefault(); en el onclick o bien la página se recargará cuando hagas click en el botón.
No necesitas pasar nada en parámetro a la función, ni mucho menos redefinir los parámetros dentro de la función. Al estar en el ámbito global, puedes acceder a ellos directamente.
No se entiende el sentido de esto: let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips"));. Si lo que pretendes es obtener el dato que se escribió en el input id="NewCrips" tienes que alcanzarlo por su id y obtener el value. Y si quieres convertir esa cadena a un array de caracteres puedes hacer algo parecido a Array.from(newCrips.value), siendo newCrips una referencia al input, como se muestra en el código más abajo.
Estás usando mal la función que obtiene los elementos por su ID, debe ser document.getElementById()  (sin s). Además, esa función es case sensitive. Si el id es id="NewUN" no lo encontrará si pones newUn. He corregido el  id del elemento. Por cierto, puedes definir la referencia a ese elemento una sola vez, en el ámbito global. Es la práctica recomendada.
No puedes usar append para un elemento de tipo input, simplemente debes cambiar su valor con value. Y, no tiene sentido que hagas return de eso.

Aplicando los cambios, debería funcionar (el código). El que encripte / desencripte ya es otra cosa (para profundizar sobre el tema, revisa los enlaces que he puesto al final).


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letters = ["A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "E", "e", "F", "f", "G", "g", "H", "h", "I", "i", "J", "j", "K", "k", "L", "l", "M", "m", "N", "n", "O", "o", "P", "p", "Q", "q", "R", "r", "S", "s", "T", "t", "U", "u", "V", "v", "W", "w", "X", "x", "Y", "y", "Z", "z"];
var special_letters = ["Ñ", "ñ", "Á", "á", "Ä", "ä", "ë", "Ë", "é", "É", "Ï", "ï", "Í", "í", "ö", "Ö", "Ó", "ó", "Ü", "ü", "ú", "Ú"];
var special_2 = [".", ",", ";", ":", "/", "*", "-", "+", "?", "¡", "!", "¿", "#", "$", "%", "&", "@", "|", "°", "]", "[", "´", "'", "¨", "-", "_", "(", ")"];
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letC = ["q", "j", "A", "i", "R", "a", "W", "T", "s", "G", "t", "h", "Y", "J", "S", "C", "b", "u", "D", "V", "H", "y", "l", "I", "o", "n", "f", "F", "Q", "p", "N", "Z", "O", "P", "x", "L", "r", "z", "k", "g", "U", "E", "m", "d", "w", "v", , "c", "B", , "M", "K", "X", "e"];
var splC = ["É", "Á", "Ë", "ä", "ñ", "Ü", "ö", "Ó", "Ö", "Í", "ï", "í", "Ñ", "Ä", "ü", "á", "ú", "ë", "ó", "Ï", "Ú", "é"];
var spC2 = ["|", "-", "¨", ")", "*", "&", ";", "/", ":", "?", "(", "_", "'", "%", "+", "¿", "[", "#", "°", "´", ".", "¡", "]", "$", ",", "@", "!", "-"];
var numC = ["7", "5", "6", "8", "2", "0", "9", "3", "4", "1"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var changelog = document.getElementById("NewUn");
var newCrips = document.getElementById("NewCrips");

function Encrip() {
  let word = newCrips.value;
  let Encrips = word.split([""]);
  let a = 0;
  let b = 0;
  let c = 0
  let d = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i > letters.length; i++) {
    if (Encrips[a] = letters[i]) {
      Encrips[a] = letC[i];
      a++;
    } else if (i = letters.length) {
      i = 0;
      a++;
    }
    if (a = Encrips.length) {
      break;
    }
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if (Encrips[b] = numbers[j]) {
      Encrips[b] = numC[j];
      b++;
    } else if (j = numbers.length) {
      j = 0;
      b++;
    }
    if (b = Encrips.length) {
      b = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (let l = 0; l < special_letters.length; l++) {
    if (Encrips[c] = special_letters[l]) {
      Encrips[c] = splC[l];
      c++;
    } else if (l = special_letters.length) {
      l = 0;
      c++;
    }
    if (c = Encrips.length) {
      c = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (let g = 0; g < special_2.length; g++) {

    if (Encrips[d] = special_2[g]) {
      Encrips[d] = spC2[g];
      d++;
    } else if (g = special_2.length) {
      g = 0;
      d++;
    }
    if (d = Encrips.length) {
      d = 0;
      break;
    }

  }

  changelog.value = Encrips.join();
}

function UnCrip() {
  alert("TODO");
}
<form action="#" method="get">

  <span class="mainb">

        <label name="crips">Inserte palabra</label>
        <input type="text" for="crips" id="NewCrips">

        <button type="submit" class="buttons" onclick="event.preventDefault();Encrip()">Encriptar</button>
        <button type="reset" class="buttons">Reiniciar</button>

        <label for="Uncrips">Desencriptar</label>
        <input type="text" for="Uncrips" id="NewUn">
        <button type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();UnCrip()" class="buttons">Uncrip</button>

    </span>
</form>




Notas

Sobre la Encriptación ver los siguientes enlaces:

¿Qué es la Encriptación?
Algoritmo criptográfico
Web Crypto API
La interfaz SubtleCrypto de la Web Crypto API
Ejemplos on line basados en Web Crypto
Diferentes códigos para encriptar - desencriptar, en el repositorio de Github de MDN




1.- Ve que pusiste getElementsById y es getElementById, le pusiste una "s" extra.
2.- Verifica que en estea linea let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips")); el valor que llega dentro del objeto string es correcto, es decir, podrias simplificar y usar "console.log(let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips")))" y ve que sale alli en tu pantalla.
3.- En las condicionales (if y/o else if) usa "==" o "===" para las comparaciones, ejemplo en: else if (i = ReadL.length). El "=" solo es para asignar valores. (usa el === mi recomendacion).
4.- En var changelog = document.getElementsById("NewUn"); fijate que llamas a "NewUn" pero en tu html lo tienes como "NewUN". Respeta las mayusculas y minisculas de los atributos de etiquetas.
5.- Las variables:
let ReadL = letters;
let ReadLC = letC;
let ReadSPL = special_letters;
let ReadSPLC = splC;
let ReadSP2 = special_2;
let ReadSPC2 =  spC2;
let ReadNum = numbers;
let ReadNumC = numC;

No hacen falta definirlas, ya tu las pasas como argumentos en tus funciones y esos son tus parametros, en lugar de definir variables y pasarle los parametros de tus funciones usa directamente los parametros. Es decir, es lugar de hacer led ReadtSP2 = special_2 para usar el ReadtSP2 usa directamente "special_2"
7.- No hace falta poner [""] en el .split, directamente pon el separador "", solo eso, ni mas.
Aqui tienes tu codigo corregido, pruebalo ahora:

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letters = ["A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e","F","f","G","g","H","h","I","i","J","j","K","k","L","l","M","m","N","n","O","o","P","p","Q","q","R","r","S","s","T","t","U","u","V","v","W","w","X","x","Y","y","Z","z"];
var special_letters = ["Ñ","ñ","Á","á","Ä","ä","ë","Ë","é","É","Ï","ï","Í","í","ö","Ö","Ó","ó","Ü","ü","ú","Ú"];
var special_2 = [".",",",";",":","/","*","-","+","?","¡","!","¿","#","$","%","&","@","|","°","]","[","´","'","¨","-","_","(",")"];
var numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var letC = ["q","j","A","i","R","a","W","T","s","G","t","h","Y","J","S","C","b","u","D","V","H","y","l","I","o","n","f","F","Q","p","N","Z","O","P","x","L","r","z","k","g","U","E","m","d","w","v",,"c","B",,"M","K","X","e"];
var splC = ["É","Á","Ë","ä","ñ","Ü","ö","Ó","Ö","Í","ï","í","Ñ","Ä","ü","á","ú","ë","ó","Ï","Ú","é"];
var spC2 = ["|","-","¨",")","*","&",";","/",":","?","(","_","'","%","+","¿","[","#","°","´",".","¡","]","$",",","@","!","-"];
var numC = ["7","5","6","8","2","0","9","3","4","1"];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


function Encrip(ReadL, ReadSP2, ReadSPL, ReadNum, ReadNumC, ReadSPC2, ReadSPLC, ReadLC) {

    let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips"));
    let Encrips = word.split(" ");

        let a = 0;
        let b = 0;
        let c = 0
        let d = 0;
    
        for(let i = 0;i > ReadL.length; i++){

            if(Encrips[a] === ReadL[i]){
                Encrips[a] = ReadLC[i];
                a++;
            }else if (i === ReadL.length) {
                i = 0;
                a++;
            }
            if(a === Encrips.length) {
                break;
            }
        }    

        for(let j = 0;j < ReadNum.length;j++){

            if(Encrips[b] === ReadNum[j]){
                Encrips[b] = ReadNumC[j];
                b++;
            }else if (j === ReadNum.length) {
                j = 0;
                b++;
            }
            if(b === Encrips.length) {
                b = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(let l = 0;l < ReadSPL.length;l++){

            if(Encrips[c] === ReadSPL[l]){
                Encrips[c] = ReadSPLC[l];
                c++;
            }else if (l === ReadSPL.length) {
                l = 0;
                c++;
            }
            if(c === Encrips.length) {
                c = 0;
                break;
            }
        } 
        for(let g = 0;g < ReadSP2.length;g++){

            if(Encrips[d] === ReadSP2[g]){
                Encrips[d] = ReadSPC2[g];
                d++;
            }else if (g === ReadSP2.length) {
                g = 0;
                d++;
            }
            if(d === Encrips.length) {
                d = 0;
                break;
            }
                        
        }
        let newUnEn = Encrips.join();
        var changelog = document.getElementById("NewUN");
        
        return(changelog.appendChild(newUnEn));
}

Saludos!.

"podrias simplificar y usar "console.log(let word = new String(document.querySelector("NewCrips")))" y ve que sale alli en tu pantalla." -> Cuidadito con la línea esta... qué pretendes que imprima una declaración / asignación??? console.log imprime lo que sea que devuelva el código que llamas dentro de la función... y la declaración y asignación de una variable no devuelven el valor asignado.

Exactamente, no busco que le devuelva un valor, es para que cuando le vuelva a fallar algo asi vea que es lo que esta devolviendo. Es como una prueba y error, lo mejor seria que haga testeos pero claro, si el no es conciente de esto prefiero solo que sepa esa alternativa para que logre ver que devuelve.  Tambien podria usar un alert u otros metodos para lograr este cometido. El objetivo es que el logre y aprenda a ver por si mismo donde esta el error y cual es ese error y ya no dependa de respuestas de otros.
Un gusto y saludos!.

Cabe destacar lo siguiente: imprimir esto no le hara caer a su codigo, a veces la gente ni se inmuta en pensar como salen las cosas en sus lineas hechas. Creo es lo mas logico que si no sabes que devuelve una cosa o no cumple con tus expectativas entonces lo mejor es ver que hay alli, sea el metodo que uses. En su caso que empiece haciendo eso, luego el ira mejorando. Ahora si, un gusto y suerte!. Doy por finalizado esta conversacion.
